# Run the trigger function on the most recent trigger in a sequence

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

In a sequence of multiple updates on a document, how can I execute the trigger on the most recent update?

```
exports.functionName = functions.firestore
  .document("collection/{docId}")
  .onUpdate((snapshot,context)=>{
     // Trigger function execution
     some_heavy_operation();
  });
```

Let's say a field is updated frequently; how can I work on the most recent update to save myself from executing some_heavy_operation() frequently?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible.  From the moment that code is deployed, every update to a matching document will trigger the function.  If you want to avoid doing some work in the trigger, you will have to write some code in it to determine if it should happen or not.